# Slack bolt - TypeError: client.chat.sendTyping is not a function

Tags: javascript, slack, slack-bolt, slack-bot

I have a slack bolt app that is on socket mode and is listening to messages using

```
app.message(/.*/, async ({ message, say, context, client, ack })=>{}
```

I would like to add a 'typing...' notification on slack after a user types a message and before the bot responds.

However, when I use this method,

```
await client.chat.sendTyping({
  token: context.botToken,
  channel: message.channel
});
```

It gives me error: **TypeError: client.chat.sendTyping is not a function**

I tried the slack documentation but couldn't get any help there as well.

How do I notify the user that the bot is 'typing...' when creating a slack bolt app in socket mode ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, sending "typing..." indicator from a 3rd party app is unsupported. There is no workaround.